# Relative path working on heroku for RoR but not on local dev environment

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have a folder under a public directory, called foo, and `domain/foo` takes me to `foo/index.html`.

I have `public/foo/assets/css/custom.css`, which is accessed with a relative link as

```
href="./assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet"
```

When the app is loaded on heroku, it loads up fine, and the view source shows the link to the CSS file as `http://example.com/foo/assets/css/custom.css`.

On local dev environment, when `rails server` is run (rails 3.2.8), the CSS is not loaded, and "view source" shows the link to the CSS file as  `http://example.com/assets/css/custom.css`, i.e. **not including** `foo/`.